# EF Code first lookup value without foreign key in model

Tags: entity-framework

I am working with a database that has two tables. 
Issues (contains a SubStatusID column that has int values. several of the rows have 0 value for this column)

SubStatus table (contains SubStatusID, SubStatusText but there is no row with 0 value for SubStatusID...so I cannot use SubStatusID from this table as the foreign key association in my entity framework model).

I also cannot change the data in any of the tables.

When I pull the Issue record using EF 5, how can I also retrieve the value of the SubStatus column if Issue's SubStatusID is not 0

Comment: Substatus seems to be a look up table. How do you want to use it? Can't you just load it beforehand and do the association on the fly in your app? I would actually use an enum for the SubstatusId column on the Issues entity and either ignore the other table (if possible) or do the join on the client. If substatus is read only you may be able to create a view where you would add the missing row (with union) and you could do the association...

Comment: @Pawel, excellent suggestions.  You are correct - it is used as a lookup table.  Let me try the suggested approach and I will let you know.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Pawel, your suggestion worked great.  I queried SubStatus table and stored it as dictionary in the Cache. Then just did a lookup from there instead of doing any associations at all.

Answer (score 0):

Substatus seems to be a look up table. How do you want to use it? Can't you just load it beforehand and do the association on the fly in your app? I would actually use an enum for the SubstatusId column on the Issues entity and either ignore the other table (if possible) or do the join on the client. If substatus is read only you may be able to create a view where you would add the missing row (with union) and you could do the association...